# How to print all the git commit message?

Tags: git, jgit

I have a git repository, I can see all the commits in a particular branch using `git log branch-name`. But I want to print the commit message, author and date of all commits with respect to a particular branch on an HTML page. Is there any solution for this?

How can I use `jgit` for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know `jgit`, but in normal git you do that with the `pretty` option as

```
git log --pretty="%ci %an %s" branch-name
```

Where `%ci` is the date (ISO), `%an` is the commiter and `%s` is the subject.

**EDIT**

You can find more info in the log documentation, pretty format section : https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_pretty_formats

Answer (score 1):

```
git log --pretty=oneline commit1...commit2 > file
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to walk every commit on the branch and wrap the output with the appropriate html tags. Now I understand you want to do it from jgit, so I'll provide an outline of how one would do it in a shell, and you will have to similarly invoke the `rev-list` functionality of **jgit**<sup>‡</sup>:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "<table style=\"width:300px\">"
for commit in $(git rev-list <your branch>); do
  git log --format="<tr><td>%cr</td><td>%an</td><td>%s</td></tr>" $commit
done
echo "</table>"
```

For different formatting options visit the [**`git-show`**](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html) help pages.

---

<sup>‡</sup> *I haven't really checked that jgit supports rev-list, but the claim on the [jgit web page](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/), as I understand it, is that it support the git core functionality. For example - see [**org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk**](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/).*